# Find which oracle database object inserts data into a particular table?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, toad

I want to find the name of the stored procedure, package, function or trigger which is inserting data into a particular table, is there any inbuilt object so that i can use it. I am searching the name of the object from last 2 hours. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find the inserted PL/SQL block, but you can try out to identify the procedures/functions referring it. And increase your chances of finding.

```
select 
   proc_syn.nam,
   proc_syn.referenced_owner, 
   proc_syn.referenced_name, 
   proc_syn.referenced_type,
   syn_tab.table_name
from 
   dba_dependencies proc_syn, dba_synonyms syn_tab, dba_tables tables
where 
      REFERENCED_TYPE in ( 'SYNONYM','TABLE')
  AND proc_syn.referenced_name = syn_tab.synonym_name
  AND syn_tab.synonym_name = tables.table_name
  AND syn_tab.owner = 'PUBLIC'
  AND REFERENCED_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
order by 
  proc_syn.referenced_owner, syn_tab.table_name;
```

The above query would return the table objects, that refer this table.

Note, this would return, when you use `STATIC` queries only. Any dynamic queries, is completely out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by analyzing all the source of your DB with something like this:

```
select *
from dba_source
where upper(text) like '%TABLE_NAME%'
```

The pro of this approach is that you will get even dynamic code; the con is that you'll have even select, update, ...

Answer (score 0):

If the table is statically referenced you can check the `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` view

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_DEPENDENCIES WHERE REFERENCED_NAME = '<your table>';
```

This will find all usages, not only insert

You can also search within source code:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_SOURCE WHERE UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%INSERT%<your table>%'
```

This will find the usage only if `INSERT` and your table are on the same line.

However if the command is built more dynamically then you will not find it that simply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user_source or user_dependencies table as below.

1. Using table **user_source**

   ```
   select  * from user_source
   where upper(text) like '%<YOUR TABLE NAME in UPPER CASE>%'
   ```

   You can select from user_source , all_source , dba_source depending on user you have logged in and permission that user have.
2. Using table **user_dependencies**

   ```
   SELECT NAME FROM user_dependencies WHERE referenced_name = '<YOUR TABLE NAME in UPPER CASE>'
   UNION
   SELECT referenced_name FROM user_dependencies WHERE name = '<YOUR TABLE NAME in UPPER CASE>'
   ```

   You can select from user_dependencies , all_dependencies , dba_dependencies depending on user you have logged in and permission that user have.